# Convert CRC uint to QByteArray QT - C++

Tags: c++, qt, crc, qbytearray, uint

I've CRC value into uint that is:

> 95DF

My target is return from uint two byte in QByteArray.

I get this:

> `CRC uint 95DF
>
> //in simple
> i should return this
>
> QByteArray[0] = 95;
> QByteArray[1] = DF;

I've tryed convert uint to QString but this one change return value.
Ho to keep the result and return QByteArray ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int value = 0x95df;
char bytes[2] = {};
bytes[0] = (value >> 8) & 0xff;
bytes[1] = value & 0xff;
QByteArray qba(bytes, 2);
```

Alternatively:

```
unsigned int value = 0x95df;
value = qToBigEndian(value); // for x86 and little endian, this puts the bytes in expected order. no-op on big-endian
QByteArray qba((char*)&value, 2);
```

Comment: with htons work correctly, instead with qToBigEndian don't work in qt. I've use htons. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Developer - I only made about a dozen typos writing that answer out.  Please double check my latest revision answer before pasting into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use QDataStream to achieve this:

```
QByteArray qba;
QDataStream qbaStream(&seq,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
qbaStream << static_cast<quint16>(value);
```